# How to Set up Thread Properties for jmeter

Tags: jmeter

can somebody please advise how to create a jmeter thread properties correctly with the following requirements 
55 user a min ramp-up over an hour with a test running for 4 hours.

Answer (score 3):

If you need 55 users added each minute during 1 hour, you set up should look like:

- Number of Threads: 3300 (55 users x 60 minutes)
- Ramp-up: 3600 (1 hour == 3600 seconds)
- Loop Count: Forever
- Scheduler -> Duration: 14400 (3600 seconds in hour x 4)

[image: Thread Group]

Be aware that 3300 concurrent threads is quite a high load, make sure that you're following recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://JMeter%20Performance%20and%20Tuning%20Tips) guide.

If you won't be able to create such a load from a single machine consider [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) when one JMeter master machine orchestrates several slaves, for instance 3 slaves having 1100 virtual users each.

Comment: this is very helpful, but what about if i wan to ramp up to 55 a min over an hour and just stay at 55 users for another hour would the above still apply, i feel like i'm ramping up my users to a lot more than 55 in the above example.

Comment: For "55 users" scenario 1. Decrease "Number of Threads" from 3300 to 55. 2. Decrease duration from 14400 to 7200.

Answer (score 1):

So you think about something like this setup I show on the screenshot below, isn't ot? It is set on jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group that comes with [jmeter plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) in standard set. You have there 55 users tat will ramp up to that value through 3600 seconds and will hold that load for next 3 hours (10800 sec).

[image: 55 users, ramp up period of 1 hour, test length 4 hours]